# Как получить курс валют используя Retrofit

Tags: java, android

Задача такова: Создать API для конвертация, у меня будет два EditText и два Spinner. На первом editText ведем значение, выбираем первый spinner (USD), и на втором spinner выбираем (RUB), а результат должен показать на втором editText. Курсы валют берем из сайт [собственно ссылка](https://api.fixer.io/latest). Как получить курсы валют с помощью Retrofit и передавать в Spinner.

Любой ответ приветствуется !

Answer (score 1):

Сам интерфейс будет выглядеть так (Retrofit2):

```
interface RestApi {
String BASE_URL = "https://api.fixer.io";
String RATES = "/latest";

@GET (RATES)
Call<Foo> getExchangeRates();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .build();

RestApi service = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
}
```

Foo - класс можете сгенерировать с помощью сервиса [www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
в который скопируете JSON ответа с вашего сайта